# find() method in CakePHP not working, tried searching around and not resolve.

Tags: cakephp, find

I'm just learning cakePHP. I have a CATEGORIES table and a POSTS table. A post have one category. So there is a category_id foreign key in POSTS table.

In my Model, I have Category.php with this code.

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Category extends AppModel {
// A hasMany association will allow us to fetch a category’s posts when we fetch a Category   record.

public $primaryKey = 'category_id';
public $hasOne = 'Post';
```

}
?>

In my Post.php I have something like this.

```
class Post extends AppModel {
   public $hasMany = array('Photo');
   public $primaryKey = 'post_id';
   public $belongsTo = array('User'); // 'Category',
   public $relatedImages;
   public $belongsTo = 'Category';
```

Now in my PostController.php I have

```
    $allCategories = $this->Category->find('list');
    $this->set('allCategories', $allCategories);
```

The objective is to retrieve all the category from the categories table and show it in my form.

However I encountered the error of Call to a member function find() on a non-object

I'm not sure what is happening here. How can I retrieve this?

many thanks!

Comment: `public $hasOne = 'Post';` What is this ?? can't 1 category have multiple posts ?? it should be hasMany relationship

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$this->Post->Category->find('list');
```

As you have to goto Category table Thru posts as u r in posts controller Now currently.

Comment: correct answer is a combination of Jquery Angry Birds and Mponos George.

Answer (score 1):

In your post model try to declare the Category as below

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
    )
);
```